# How to enter Redux statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Redux toolkits view:

[image]

I have some statements in **Redux** toolkits and I can't enter some of them.
I already tried this version, but it gives me error.

```
  const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);
  const { order, loading, error } = orderDetails;
```

And then in return:

```
 <p>Shipping: {order.shippingAddress.country}</p>
```

It gives this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'country')
```

Comment: order (as shown in the screenshot) does not have a property named shippingAddress. order has a property named data, under which shippingAddress can be found.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis no, it has properties like City, Country and etc.My bad, i forgot to click on shippingAddress

Comment: Additionally `data` is an array of objects which _contain_ those various properties.

Comment: @Sanchosmore the above comment is actually right, he was referring to the `shippingAddress` being nested inside `order.data[0].shippingAddress.country` try that

Comment: @Aleksandar it's work, thk u very much

Answer (score 0):

Going by your screenshot, `order` has a data property that is an array, that *then* contains `shippingAddress` - and I assume that `order` is sometimes `undefined`.

You would be accessing

`order.data[0].shippingAddress.country`

and to prevent errors if any of those are `undefined`, you'd do

`order?.data?.[0]?.shippingAddress.country`

Answer (score -2):

Try accessing your data using optional chaining it will help you solving TypeErrors like this :

```
<p>Shipping: {order?.shippingAddress?.country}</p>
```

Comment: I already tried it, but it always give null

Comment: Hmm..probably the data you are trying to access is not there in the first place. Have you console log the data when you saved it in the state ?